# Multipe :target elements in one page

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with keeping one a href's target active while clicking another button within the main ID.

When you click the INTEL button it's opacity moves from 0 to 1. But when you click Data History within INTEL the whole box vanishes when it is supposed to show a smaller box to the right.

[Here is the link to the code.](http://codepen.io/Ephah/pen/yMQMJm)

```
    #intel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  background-color: #BAB5A1;
  height: 245px;
  width: 790px;
  color: #454138;
  font-family: inherit;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

#intel:target, #inteldatahistory:target {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}

#inteldatahistory {
  color: #454138;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: A page can only have one target at a time. You can tell because a page URL may only have one fragment identifier at a time. There is a 1:1 mapping between the two. You will need to do this with something other than the :target pseudo.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#intelbutton').on('click', function(){
        $('#intel').css('opacity','1');
    });
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Is there a chance that I could be done using just CSS? I doubt it but I may be missing something.  Thanks.

Comment: Let me try in another way. As far as I know this issue could be fixed only by scripting. Anyways, I will check for another solution.

Comment: Sorry @MitchellBrock, I guess you have to go with script.

Comment: That's okay, thanks for the help!